# Residue of $f(z) = \sin(πz)/(z-1)^3$

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the residue of $f(z) = \sin(πz)/(z-1)^3$ at $z=1$? Do I have to find the Taylor series of $\sin(πz)$ around $1$ to make my life easier? I know that $1$ is a pole of order $3$, but how does that help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pole is of order $2$ because $\sin \pi z$ has a simple zero at $z=1$. You can either use the Taylor expansion very easily or use the following formula for the residue at an order-$p$ pole:$$b_1={1\over (p-1)!}\lim_{z\to z_0}{d^{p-1}\over dz^{p-1} }z^pf(z)\Bigg|_{z=z_0}$$